# PrettyPhoto doesnt popup only online?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm currently experiencing an issue with [prettyPhoto](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/) playing youtube videos. Playing the video locally on my machine it will work like the below:

[image: screenshot]

However, uploading the site online and when clicking the same shortcut it loads at the bottom of the page like below

[image: screenshot]

If you need to look at my code please ask. I'm just puzzled to why this works locally and not online. The file structure is exactly the same.

Comment: Check the paths to your CSS and Javascript files. Something isn't loading by the looks of things.

Comment: I'll check that, just find it strange how it's working locally but not online.

Answer (score 2):

3rror404 is most likely right. I've had path issues when using pretty photo before.

Check if the paths are relative or absolute. You might also want to check inside the JavaScript/CSS files to make sure those paths line up.

- /css/prettyPhoto.css - relative path type
- http://example.com/css/prettyPhoto.css - absolute

If you're pretty confident that it's not a path issue then i would check for JavaScript errors within the page. You could use Google Chromes debugger or grab Firebug for Firefox.

Good Luck!